# Integration tests y appsettings, ¿Cómo modificarlo?

Tags: c#, test, configuración, appsettings

Estoy haciendo unos *integration tests*, o tests de integración en donde necesito modificar mi *appsettings*, entonces he creado mi archivo appsettings3.json.

La historia es la siguiente: desde mi test de integración creo un cliente que se conecta a mi api, pero necesito modificar mi api porque usa *appsettings* pero para testeo necesito borrar su *appsettings* y coger *appsettings3*. Bueno, pues no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

Mi test:

```
        _factory = factory;
        _client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        });

//codigo

            var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        services.AddScoped<IService, TestService>();                     }
                });
            }).CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });

var response = await client.GetAsync($"...");



public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Create a new service provider.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            }
        });
    }
```

He mirado como cambiar este *setting* y no he visto nada mas que cambiar *environments*, alguna ayuda? El motivo por el que no quiero usar distintos entornos es que son muchos tests, y esto seria mas confuso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues ya está solucionado. Googleando un poco, y gracias a stackoverflow encontré la manera de hacerlo:

```
    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(b => {
        b.Sources.Clear();
        // this is an appsettings file located in the test-project!
        b.AddJsonFile("appsettings3.json", false);
    }
    );
```

se añade a ConfigureWebHost